# 18.04 powers off during boot or soon thereafter

Tags: boot, 18.04, shutdown

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 system that I created to provide remote access to our office March 2020, when the COVID-19 lockdowns started.  It has been running great since then ... until an update a couple days ago. Now it runs for no more than a few minutes and often powers itself down *during the boot sequence* without ever reaching the login prompt!  That makes it **extremely** difficult to work on, to say the least.

I used my phone to video the boot sequence (because it disappears too fast to read) and found that when it powers down during a power on sequence, the last message logged to the screen is this:

```
[  3.144966] fb: switching to nouveaufb from VESA VGA
```

After that, the screen goes black and the power light on the computer goes out.

Is there any way to recover from this?  FYI:  I'm no linux/ubuntu expert, so I may need a few more details than are sometimes provided in answers here... (smile)  I will try to discover any information requested, but I need to be able to collect it FAST during my very limited time when I can login (and those are few.)

**EDIT**:  The video card WAS an EVGA e-GeForce 7950 GT, but I pulled that and replaced it with the oldest, plain old VGA card I could find that would fit in the same slot (I could not find a manufacturer or model name on the VGA card.)  I am currently booted with this card and waiting to see how long the system continues operating.  The computer is a Dell Precision 390 and the only hardware changes (from the standard factory config) are a second NIC and the video card.

*Prior* to replacing the video card, I tried booting the previous version of the system, which was `(GNU/Linux 4.15.0-141-generic x86_64)` instead of `(GNU/Linux 4.15.0-142-generic x86_64)`.  Unfortunately, I had the same results.

With the new (actually quite OLD) video card, the system has been running for 12+ minutes, so far, which is at least 6 minutes longer than it was running with the GeForce card.  Hopefully the older hardware fixed my problem.  This is a server with no X system, so a plain VGA is perfectly acceptable, too.  If it mysteriously powers itself off again, I will post another edit to this.  Until then, thank you!

**EDIT 2**: I will probably never know why an update caused my system to power itself off because replacing the GeForce with a very old VGA card has allowed the system to remain up for nearly seven hours -- so far -- when it had been running no more than 5 or 6 minutes, if it didn't power off during the boot.  So, it is working well enough for me.

Comment: I think the question needs more details like GPU model etc.

Comment: Did the update include a new kernel? If yes, can you boot to the previous kernel?